# CakePHP 3: Http Client after reading large XML Kill process, how to clear memory?

Tags: php, cakephp, memory-management, memory-leaks, cakephp-3.0

```
// loop multiple sources
foreach ($sources as $source) {
          $this->remote($source['url']);
          sleep(10);
      }
//
```

then grab remote xml, and reading results, but after reading first large xml, next will kill process..

```
public function remote($fileUrl)
{
  try {
    $http = new Client();
    $results = $http->get($fileUrl,[], ['timeout' => 2000]);
    $xml = $results->xml; // <----------- 1st success, then kill next loop

    //$this->prepare_data($xml);
    $http = null;
    $results = null;
    $xml = null;

  } catch (\Exception $e) {
      \Cake\Log\Log::error("File does not exists or can't read!", "error");
      \Cake\Log\Log::error($e->getMessage(), 'error');
  }
  return true;
}
```

I have this problem only at testing and master server (**platform.sh**), at developer localhost no problem.

How to clear memory && free resourse after first loop?

Comment: You have a timeout of 2000 (milliseconds?), yet `sleep()` for 10 seconds. Maybe that?

Comment: sleep (pause) just in loop, get method don't produce problems, this all for testing purpose, while i trying to find where is problem.

Comment: and what does the cake log say?

Comment: nothing, it's empty, no errors. I think this is related to memory usage..

Comment: if it was memory, it would produce an error, how do you know that the process was killed?

Comment: output in console: "Killed"

Answer (score 0):

Its probably php timeout, you can (not recommended):

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

But i recommend you to make this process run in background by using the CakePHP Shell, see https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells.html#the-cakephp-console